# g++ invalid initialization error using boost::algorithm:string:split and std::string

Tags: c++, string, boost

I am porting some C++ code from Windows to Linux (and eventually OSX). Tons of C++ issues arise due to Windows non-compliance. I seem to have gotten past that, but am now facing a boost problem.

Basically, I want to chop up a string where the substrings of interest are separated by commas, and shove those into a string vector. This results in errors in g++, but it works fine compiling with Visual Studio

This program illustrates the issue exactly:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main (void) {


  std::vector<std::string> str_vec;
  std::string str_to_split = "this,is,the,string,to,split";

  boost::algorithm::split(str_vec,
                          str_to_split.substr(1, str_to_split.size()-2),
                          boost::algorithm::is_any_of(","),
                          boost::algorithm::token_compress_on);


  return 0;
}
```

To compile I do: `>> g++ -o foo foo.cpp`

This is my terminal output:

```
foo.cpp: In function 'int main()':
foo.cpp:11:54: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference type 'std::basic_string<char>&' from an rvalue of type'std::basic_string<char>'
   boost::algorithm::split(str_vec,str_to_split.substr(1, str_to_split.size()-2),boost::algorithm::is_an
                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/algorithm/string.hpp:23:0,
                 from foo.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp:140:35: note:   initializing argument 2 of 'equenceSequenceT& boost::algorithm::split(SequenceSequenceT&, RangeT&, PredicateT, boost::algorithm::token_compress_mode_type) [with SequenceSequenceT = std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >; RangeT = std::basic_string<char>; PredicateT = boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>]'
         inline SequenceSequenceT& split(
                               ^
```

Comment: It is pretty clear. Boost wants a non-const reference for it's second argument (I imagine, it modifes it), and you can't bind non-const reference to temporary.

Comment: @SergeyA: I could never figure out why it would need a non-const ref here or why it'd modify the input to a split function.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet, no idea either, but: `This function is equivalent to C strtok` (from Boost), and `strtok` modifies it's argument. Probably someone just copied behavior?

Answer (score 3):

This function takes `std::string&` rather than `std::string` or `const std::string&`. That means you'll have to store the result of `.substr` in an intermediate variable then pass the variable to `boost::algorithm::split`. It'll be clearer code anyway.

FWIW, I have no idea *why* the function is designed this way. Seems odd to me but there you go.

Comment: yeesh. I was hoping I could avoid having to do that!

Comment: @dmedine: I've had an "extra" line of code in my codebase for years because of this! Honestly, though, it would probably be clearer anyway if you make `str_to_split` the actual string you're going to split, with a `str_to_split = str_to_split.substr(...)`.

Comment: I think I've seen the split API compatible with containers of `boost::string_ref`. That would be very dangerous if the argument could be a temp. I'm not sure that applies here.

Comment: @dmedine Wild suggestion - open boost sources and add another overload for `split`, which would accept the source string via rvalue reference and than call the original split. No idea how is going to work, though :)

Comment: @SergeyA: That's a terrible idea

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet, why? It would end up modifying the temporary, but why is that such a terrible thing?

Comment: @SergeyA: You don't think locally modifying the Boost source is a terrible thing to do?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet, no, we do it all the time. Boost is not free from issues. For example, we add mpl containers which can hold more types than default version. Other than violating sacred Boost, do you see a real problem? And if you really dislike editing boost files, you can always create another file and just extend boost namespace in it.

Comment: @SergeyA: 100% non-portability, you lose your changes as soon as you update Boost, you're meddling in code you may not fully understand, how are you going to version control it (clone the entire Boost repo? ew) you may break other projects also built on your machine, etc etc etc ... this is _not_ the way to modify or to extend 3rd party libraries! If you want to wrap `boost::algorithm::split` then do so but put the new function in your own namespace for goodness's sake!! No way a Boost code mod passes code review in my team, unless it's utterly, utterly unavoidable and exceedingly temporary.

Comment: Extending boost namespace locally will save you from breaking other projects and non-portability on a given boost version. On any rate, this is something people decide for themselves. Unfortunately, boost is not a library which is free from problems, and sometimes you need to fix them somehow.

Comment: @SergeyA The only valid reason to modify foreign code (Boost or anything) is to fix bugs (not subjective "issues" such a limitations). And then you advertise the issue so that the bug is also fixed in the official project, and next update will overwrite the fix with another fix. (If not, it means the project is badly maintained and you probably has many other serious issues.)

Comment: @SergeyA for you http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/limit-vector-size.html is the proper way to allow for MPL containers with more elements

Comment: In the end it was just the one 'extra' line of code. What bugs me is that this is legal in Windows and not elsewhere. I deal with so much code that was written in Windows and then needs to be cross-platformized. It would be nice if I didn't have to spend a day compile-tweak-repeat only to end up with code that compiles with g++ and clang but not MSVC!

Comment: @dmedine: IIRC you can turn that extension off in VS

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet: Yeah, but my colleagues who write the code in the first place don't ;)

Comment: @dmedine: Ah well that's what code review is for (and secret rendition)

Comment: @sehe, only you still need to add files like `vector60.hpp` if you want to go beyond currently available 50 elements.

Comment: @SergeyA Are you sure that's not just because of the (mentioned) [`BOOST_MPL_CFG_NO_PREPROCESSED_HEADERS`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/configuration.html#id1598)?

Comment: @sehe, I am away from my office right now (thanks god!), so I can't give you 100% guarantee that this is not defined somewhere in our sources. But I am 99.9% sure we are not doing it (because why would we?). If you want, I can verify tomorrow.

Comment: @SergeyA: You would do it to solve the problem that you described, in the documented and supported manner.

Comment: You'd not do it "in your sources". You'd do it in your config. Which is the one file you can override or you can supply the tweaks in your build files. "Why would we?" - erm. because you wanted more than 50 elements

Comment: @sehe, oh, I see it now. We need to define this variable so that the option would take effect, and preprocess the headers for every compilation. Thanks, but no. It suits us much better to have a pregenerated file. You see, our compilation time is big enough already, without us preprocessing the mpl for every translation unit we use it within (and we have a lot of those).

Comment: Hehehe. I can only imagine the compile times if you use MPL containers of 60 elements.

Comment: @sehe, yes. They are quite high :) Unfortunately, this is a a result of some design choices we made several years ago, and now we have to proceed with this.